# Kubernetes: Putting JSON value in YAML file

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create a secret from a JSON value but I keep getting this error executing `"secrets.yaml" at <b64enc>: wrong type for value; expected string; got map[string]interface {}` when I do `helm install`.

**secrets.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
  namespace: wp-{{ .Values.name }}
  labels:
    app: wp-{{ .Values.name }}
type: Opaque
data:
  credentials.json: {{ .Values.dbCred | b64enc }}
```

**values.yaml**

```
dbCred: {
  'type': '',
  'project_id': '',
  'private_key_id': '',
  'private_key': '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',
  'client_email': '',
  'client_id': '',
  'auth_uri': '',
  'token_uri': '',
  'auth_provider_x509_cert_url': '',
  'client_x509_cert_url': ''
}
```

Comment: Try `toJson .Values.dbCred | b64enc`. Or you could even try putting the values in json structure in the values.yaml as yaml and letting helm convert to json for you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53342487/9705485

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by changing `{{ .Values.dbCred | b64enc }}` to `{{ toJson .Values.dbCred | b64enc }}`

Comment: I tried putting that secrets.yaml and values entry into an example chart generated with `helm create` and was able to recreate the error. I then made this change and found I then don't get the error

Comment: @O’Dane Brissett Bit confused by the question. This example discussed is a secrets.yaml

Comment: I'm using octopus deploy to set the variable then substitute the values in my helm. However using the example above i get the error `did not find expected key`

Comment: @O’Dane Brissett I'd suggest trying it outside of octopus, If that works then you know it's a problem at the octopus level. If it doesn't work then I'd suggest a new question on SO or an issue on the helm repo.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can keep your **credentials.json** file inside chart directory, and [access file inside your template](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files.md)

```
data:
  credentials.json: {{ .Files.Get "credentials.json" | b64enc }}
```

Comment: So slick!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use double-quote("") before and after `dbCred` as below

```
dbCred: "{
  'type': '',
  'project_id': '',
  'private_key_id': '',
  'private_key': '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',
  'client_email': '',
  'client_id': '',
  'auth_uri': '',
  'token_uri': '',
  'auth_provider_x509_cert_url': '',
  'client_x509_cert_url': ''
}"
```

Other things look okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow for your configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
  namespace: wp-{{ .Values.name }}
  labels:
    app: wp-{{ .Values.name }}
type: Opaque
data:
  credentials.json: |-
     {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/_helper_conf.tpl") . | b64enc }}
```

Please note that when you are trying to inject configuration into secret ( espacially large ones ) you might need to use **|-**

you can also use a helper like

```
{{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/_helper_conf.tpl") . | b64enc }}
```

Or even better, in you yaml configuration ( values.yml )
you can just write as follow:

```
dbCred:
  type: ''
  project_id: ''
  private_key_id: ''
  private_key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
  client_email: ''
  client_id: ''
  auth_uri: ''
  token_uri: ''
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: ''
  client_x509_cert_url: ''
```

to use this sort of configuration you can check the object bellow:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
  namespace: wp-{{ .Values.name }}
  labels:
    app: wp-{{ .Values.name }}
type: Opaque
data:
  credentials.json: |-
     {{ toJson .Values.dbCred | b64enc }}
```

The use of this configuration is to provide an abstraction of the json provided and put it inside your values.yml

```
{{ toJson .Values.dbCred | b64enc }}
```

Note that this might be duplicated if you support multiple environments, so you might prefer to use a helper and some variables inside ( or tpl ) to avoid duplicated code

I hope this helps